# how to remove codeigniter functions from base url when routing

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, url-routing

I routed my controller function and suddenly the function name is added to base URL, how can I remove this?

```
 $route['editblog/(:num)']='Code/editblog/$1';
```

Then all of the sudden edit blogs are added to base URL and my external files are showing an error.

```
<script src="assests/vendor/slick/slick.min.js">
```

It shows:

```
<script src="editblog/assests/vendor/slick/slick.min.js">
```

Please help me, help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: try to change your base_url to `$config['base_url'] = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/webdir";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to verify 1 things:

- application/config.php `$config['base_url'] = 'application/path/';` like `http://example.com/` or `http://localhost/applicationName/`

Now you should use urls like

- base_url('assets/js/filename/js');
- base_url('controller/action/parameters');

In this way, it will generate correct urls.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your URL's to:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assests/vendor/slick/slick.min.js'); ?>">
```

Actually `base_url` is set in your `applications/config.php` file. -> `config['base_url']`. It **MUST** include trailing slash

Comment: can you tell anyother choice is there

Comment: because nearly 92 links

Comment: You could add trailing slash `/` in front of every link, but you have to change all the links again. Another solution is using your `.htaccess` file to rewrite all of your assets.

Comment: can you share the htacess file

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /admin.cricerzz.com/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|assests|uploads|images|js|css|vendor|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `.htaccess` for that. I really recommend you to spend some time and edit your links.

Answer (score 0):

in your config file:

$config['base_url'] = 'http://test.com';

when you call out the **base_url()**. You can use this :

```
<script src="<?= base_url().'/assests/vendor/slick/slick.min.js'; ?>">
```